# Text to speech without a Network Connection?

Tags: windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

Android has a TTS library. It works without a network connection. Does an analog of this library exist for windows phone? I see only Bing's API for using TTS, but this requires a network connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at present.  You need a internet connection as MS have not provided an API in the OS yet.